# In a list, perform a task depending on the index values?

Tags: python, list, indexing, while-loop, task

Ok, so I have been trying to get specific indexes in my list "beans" to perform a task depending on the value of that index.

Here is the code:

```
def dude():
    beans = ['639', '939']
    bun = 0
    heyo_beans = beans[bun]
    while bun in range(len(beans)):   
        while bun in range(len(beans)):
            try:
                b = heyo_beans.index('639')
            except ValueError:
                print("Do Nothing")
                break
            else:
                print("Do something with variable b")
                break
        bun = bun + 1
        print(bun)
    print(beans[1])
dude()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Do something with variable b
1
Do something with variable b
2
939
```

I should be getting:

```
Do something with variable b
1
Do Nothing
2
939
```

"Do Nothing" should appear the second go around as the index changed to index 2, which is 939.
The final output of 939 is to verify that bean index 1 is indeed 939.
Any ideas?

Another example would be:

```
list = ['111', '222', '333']
#goes through the list in a while loop, each time adding +1 index, for range in length
if list index = 111:
    "Perform task A"
elif list index = 222:
    "Perform task B"
elif list index = 333:
    "Perform task C"
else:
    "Do Nothing"
list index = index + 1
```

Any suggestions on how to make this work?

This also does not work:

```
def dude():
    list_to_beans = ['639', '939']
    bun = 0
    heyo_beans = list_to_beans[bun]
    while bun in range(len(list_to_beans)):   
        for bun in list_to_beans:
            if heyo_beans == '639':
                print("Do something")
            else:
                print("Do nothing")
        bun = bun + 1
    print(bun)

    
dude()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Do something
Do something
```

Should say:

```
Do something
Do nothing
2
```

Comment: Did you really intend to have two nested `while bun` loops>?

Comment: Why should the second iteration do anything different? The result of `heyo_beans.index('639')` doesn't change depending on `bun`.

Comment: What't the point of a loop that always executes `break`?

Comment: Why don't you use `for item in list:`? BTW, don't use `list` as a variable name, it's the name of a built-in function.

Comment: This is just a basic example to get the point across. The function needs to go through every index in the list and do something defferent depending on that index. More complex that you think. I can explain it to you, I can't understand it for you. Also, the list I am using is created based on the users input. That means the list won't always be the same.

Comment: `for item in list:` goes through every index in the list.

Comment: You seem to be confusing list indexes with list elements. The indexes are 0, 1, 2, ...., the elements are 111, 222, 333.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I understand. I'll try this and if it doesn't work I'll let you know!

Answer (score 0):

You're making this way more complicated than it needs to be. Just use an ordinary `for` loop to iterate over all the elements of the list. You're confusing indexes with the elements.

Since the list contains strings, you have to compare with strings, not numbers.

```
mylist = ['111', '222', '333']
for item in mylist:
    if item == '111':
        "Perform task A"
    elif item == '222':
        "Perform task B"
    elif item == '333':
        "Perform task C"
    else:
        "Do Nothing"
```

Comment: This does not work...

Comment: Then I guess I really don't understand what you want to do. Try posting a real example instead of pseudocode.

Comment: You have to use `==` to compare, not `=`.

Comment: ok got it working

Comment: thanks for the help Barmar, I appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
def dude():
    list_to_beans = ['639', '939']
    bun = 0
    heyo_beans = list_to_beans[bun]
       
    for heyo_beans in list_to_beans:
        if heyo_beans == '639':
            print("Do something")
        else:
            print("Do nothing")
    bun = bun + 1
    print(bun)

    
dude()
```

OUTPUT:

```
Do something
Do Nothing
1
```